# How can I check if a bean has been loaded by springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to run some Grpc beans using Springboot and all I see confirmed is the springboot application loads.  Where can I find confirmation that the beans loaded? Is there a way to start springboot so that it will show this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The below code will log all the beans being loaded by spring application in its container:-

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext appContext;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        String[] beans = appContext.getBeanDefinitionNames();
        Arrays.sort(beans);
        for (String bean : beans) {
            System.out.println(bean);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

[Jaspret's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56214353/1534211) shows a good way.
You could also use a bean lifecycle methods in a following way:

1) Add `@PostConstruct` annotation:

```java
@PostConstruct
public void constructed() {
    System.out.println("I was constructed!");
}
```

or
2) Implement `InitializingBean` interface on your bean:

```java
@Component
public class MyClass implements InitializingBean {
  // ...

  @Override
  public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
      System.out.println("I was constructed!");
  }
}
```

to let your bean "notify" you that they were constructed.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I think it's worth mentioning that you obtain more detailed information about the beans that are being loaded by using the property bellow. This will show the beans and their conditions (from `@Conditional` like annotations), indicating why a bean was or was not loaded.

```yaml
# For application.yml
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure: DEBUG
```

```
# For application.properties
logging.level.org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging=DEBUG
```

That can be particularly useful in cases where you don't have control over the bean's code, such as when it's loaded from an external library (which was my case, and the reason I came here).